# Turn Firefox location bar into search box

Tags: firefox

I'd like to change the default behavior of the location bar in Firefox to search Google unless I specifically enter a domain name, and I don't mean just changing the location bar from Google's 'feeling lucky' to a normal Google SERP.

For example, typing in `Superuser` will take me to the Google [SERP](http://www.google.co.uk/search?btnG=Google+Search&q=superuser) but typing in `Superuser.com` will take me to the [website](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something else to try is going to **about:config** and then changing the **keyword.URL** value.

By default it is set to this:
http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=

Try changing it to this and see if it makes a difference:
**http://www.google.com/search?q=**

Comment: Molly ownage. =)

Answer (score 5):

kinda like the [omnibar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8823)? Single search/url bar, which searches to a search engine of your choice unless its an exact url.

Answer (score 1):

I have Firefox 3.5.2 and this is the default behavior. I haven't set up any features or settings. Maybe you have an old version, prior to them adding the 'smart bar' feature.. try updating here http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/personal.html

Comment: Interesting. I have that version and it takes me to Wikipedia via a Google search. It is definitely performing a Google "I'm Feeling Lucky" search.

Comment: kpoehls is right, this is the default behaviour, maybe you have continiously updated from an older version with different default settings.

Answer (score 1):

> For user who prefer to see a list of
>   matching websites or search results
>   instead of auto redirect to a web page
>   when entering keywords in the
>   Firefox’s link location bar, it’s
>   possible to change the Firefox
>   behavior by modifying its
>   configuration using steps below.

Enter about:config into the address bar.

Locate keyword.url or type keyword.url into “Filter” text box to search for it.

Double click on the line of “keyword.url”.

By default, the string value for “keyword.url” is “about:neterror?e=query&u=”. To display search results instead, replace the string with one of the following search statements, depending on the search engine you prefer (e.g. Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=)

Click OK when done.

[Source & more info](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/06/12/hack-to-modify-firefox-3-address-bar-to-return-search-results-when-query-or-invalid-url-is-entered/)